# Markov Chain transitional probability query.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Say I have the transitional probability matrix P= $\begin{bmatrix}.8 & .2\\.6 & .4\end{bmatrix}$ And the entry (1,1) denotes the probability that I stay in state 0, (1,2) I move from state 0 to state 1, (2,1) I move from state 1 to state 0 and (2,2) stay in state 1. Now suppose I am on day 1 and in state 0, and I want to find the probability that I will remain in state 0 over day 2, 3 and 4. Am I right in thinking that I compute $P^2 \ entry (1,1) + P^3 \ entry (1,1)+P^4 \ entry (1,1). $
And for when I need to find the probability of being in state 0 on day 4, I only compute $P^4 \ entry (1,1)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed -  this follows from the definition of $P$ and matrix arithmetic...

Comment: I'm confused by your notation.  What does  $P^2 \ entry (1,1)$ mean?

Comment: This would be the probability matrix times itself and then I would be observing the first row first column entry corresponding to staying in state 0.

Comment: The probability to remain in state 0 over days 2, 3 and 4 knowing that on day 1 one is in state 0 is $(P_{11})^3=(.8)^3$. Note that the sum you propose could be $\gt1$.

Comment: That makes sense but in that case what would be the probability that I am in state 0 on day 4. The same?

Comment: @Did you are right, sorry for the mistake. $P^2(1,1)$ includes possibilities of $P(1,1)$, so that needs to be accounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revising my opinion, based on comment of @Did. I would like explain his answer in detail to make sure you avoid my mistake.

Let $X_t$ be the position of your process at time $t$. You start with $X_1 = 0$.

You would like to end up with $X_2 = 0$. The probability of that event is $P_{11}$. Since your Markov chain is time homogeneous,
$$\mathbb{P}[X_3 = 0|X_2 = 0] = \mathbb{P}[X_2 = 0|X_1 = 0] = P_{11}.$$
So, to go from $X_1 = 0$ to $X_2 = 0$, it's also a transition with probability $P_{11}$.

Now, what is the probability of tracing that path entirely?
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[X_3 = 0,X_2=0|X_1 = 0]
  &= \mathbb{P}[X_3 = 0|X_2 = 0,X_1 = 0] \cdot \mathbb{P}[X_2 = 0|X_1 = 0] \\
  &= \mathbb{P}[X_3 = 0|X_2 = 0] \cdot \mathbb{P}[X_2 = 0|X_1 = 0] \\
  &= \left(P_{11}\right)^2.
\end{split}
$$

Along similar lines, you can show
$$
\mathbb{P}[X_n = 0,X_{n-1}=0, \ldots, X_2=0|X_1 = 0] = \left(P_{11}\right)^{n-1}.
$$

Comment: Brilliant!, after looking at that and actually writing out each path way it became clear. So the probability of staying in state 0 on all of day 2,3 and 4 will just be 0.8*0.8*0.8.

Comment: @xiA Exactly - $(P_{11})^3 = 0.8^3 = 0.512$.

Comment: Whereas the probability of being in state 0 on day 4 is produced by the matrix multiplication and observing the correct entry. =.752 in this case

Comment: @xiA Yes, in other words $(P^3)_{11}$.