# Markov Chain Transition Probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains

When dealing with markov chains, say I am in state 0 on day 1, is the probability that I will be in state 0 on day 4 equal to the probability that I will be in state 0 on all of day 2, day 3 and day 4? I believe these are equivalent because to get from day 1 to day 4, you have to transition day 1-day 2 , day 2 - day 3 and day 3 - day 4.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to be in the same states on days 2 and 3. For example, the states could be $0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 0$ or $0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 0$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. To be in state 0 on day 4, you may be in state 1 on day 2, stae 2 on day 3 and jump to 0 on day 4. Any path which ends at 0 on day 4 will be good enough.

Being in that state all the time (not going anywhere) is one of the possibilities, but not necessarily the exclusive one.

If it is not possible to jump away from state 0, then the two are equivalent and happen with probability 1 (give that you are in state 0 on day 1 already).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I asked a similar question earlier about this and you said that I would be right in adding P^2 entry(1,1) + P^3 entry(1,1)+P^4 entry(1,1) to find the probability of staying in state 0 over all day 2, day 3 and day 4. But another user said this was incorrect and gave the example that the probability could be >1 and I computed it to be greater than one. The url of that question is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404432/markov-chain-transitional-probability-query

Comment: @xiA You are right, that answer is wrong. $P^2(1,1)$ already includes the possibility of $P^1(1,1)$ so that needs to be accounted for. A simple addition will not do, my mistake.

Comment: @xiA I just posted an answer to the question there clarifying the right approach.